# Modify variable in Inner class Java

Tags: java, variables, inner-classes

I have a problem with Java inner classes which I can't figure out. Suppose you have

```
class Outer
{
     int outer = 0;
     class Inner
     {
          int inner = Outer.this.outer; //(or just outer as it is not shadowed)
          inner = 3; //or whatever, even outer = 3
     }
}
```

Well, when I write the last assignment I get the compilation error

```
Syntax error on token ";", , expected
```

on the precedent line.

Why I cannot modify inner?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have a statement outside a method. One technique would be to use an *instance initializer block*:

```
class Outer
{
     int outer = 0;
     class Inner
     {
          int inner = Outer.this.outer; //(or just outer as it is not shadowed)
          // instance initializer block:
          {
              inner = 3; //or whatever, even outer = 3
          }
     }
}
```

Alternatively, define a constructor:

```
class Outer
{
     int outer = 0;
     class Inner
     {
          int inner = Outer.this.outer; //(or just outer as it is not shadowed)
          Inner() {
              inner = 3; //or whatever, even outer = 3
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to place the code in a method or in the constructor:

```
class Outer
{
     int outer = 0;
     class Inner
     {
          int inner = Outer.this.outer; 
          public Inner() {
               inner = 3; 
          }

          public increment() {
               inner++;
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your assignment to `inner` must be inside a method or constructor, not "loose" in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the line:

```
 inner=3;
```

in a method in the inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can not directly initialize  `inner = 3;` outside method.Make sure that `inner = 3;`  inside any method or constructor.

```
 public Inner() 
 {
       inner = 3; 
 }
```